# Music recognition software for Linux based on the song melody

Tags: linux, music

Does anybody know an application which recognizes any melody (like Tunatic on Windows)?
I would like to be able to sing on the microphone and to recognize what I am singing, or at least to recognize it if I play the melody itself in the microphone.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have internet access, [Midomi](http://www.midomi.com/) will do the trick. You need flash player, but it does work under linux.

- It works with singing, as opposed to software such as [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) which uses files fingerprints.
- It works under Linux because it isn't OS-specific.
- It does a good job at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/) in Linux by installing [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

1. Install wine, winetricks, Tunatic.
2. Wine > Settings > Applications, add Tunatic.exe, imitate Windows XP (or 98)
3. In Libraries add "pthreadDVC2.dll"
4. Install core fonts through winetricks (optional)

It should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

I have just uploaded zhavam to github (https://github.com/ipserc/zhavam)

It uses ACRCloud for retrieving the song facts of the music yuo're reproducing in your Linux box.

The only thing you need is to create a free account on ACR Cloud and put your access data in zhavan.conf. You can use the config editor of zhavam to do this.

For running zhavam you need to put libacrcloud_recognizer.so in your system and update ldconf or use LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/acrcloud.